# Where can i find all bootstrap icons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I found one example where with data-icon = "value", bootstrap is loading some images.
I have bootstrap cdn,i went to the official site of bootstrap but i can't find these icon with these values.How and where can i find these icons that are included in the select options ?

```
<select class="selectpicker">
<option value="pkr" data-icon="pkr">PKR</option>
<option value="uk" data-icon="gbp">GBP</option>
<option value="usd" data-icon="usd">USD</option>
<option value="eu" data-icon="euro">EURO</option>
<option value="aud" data-icon="aud">AUD</option>
<option value="afg" data-icon="afg">AFG</option>
</select>
```

I found the code on:

Comment: what template are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> Bootstrap doesn’t include an icon library by default [...].

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/extend/icons/. Try using https://fontawesome.com/.

Answer (score -1):

If your project is using bootstrap 3 then you can find it here just use the end word after glyphicon https://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/
If it’s bootstrap 4+ https://fontawesome.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/